# ASP.NET Databinding A grid as a selection list

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, datasource

**Context:**
I have a Query that returns a list of availables[choices]. I have an entity that has a list of [values]. I want to give the user a grid with the [choices], and depending on what [choices] are checked/selected, I would like to have those [value] of those [choices] assigned to the [entity]'s [values].

That is a fairly standard request, but my question is this:  Is it possible to do this type of databinding declaratively?  That is, can I do this databinding with a combination of only datasource controls and binding expressions?  How would you define a binding expression/data source that would allow a list of values to be bound to the selected item values from a grid bound to a different list without using event handlers and manually extracting the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you outer join the two queries so that you get something like:

```
select c.id, c.item, decode(s.id,null,'N','Y') selected
  from color c, selections s
 where c.id=s.id (+)
```

Please forgive the Oracle syntax, OJ & decode() however you need.  `:)`

```
ID    Item     Selected
--    -----    --------
1     Blue     N
2     Red      Y
3     Green    Y
```

Then, databind the `selected` property to that new `selected` column.

**UPDATE:**

```
sSQL = "select c.id, c.name, case c.id "
for each e as entity in entitycollection
  sSQL &= "when " & e.id & " then 'Y' "
next
sSQL &= " else 'N' end selected "
sSQL &= "from color"
```

Naturally, you'd do this from a StringBuilder, not these concatenations, but you get the idea.  :)

Comment: That was the first route I was going down.  I have a list of a value type which the grid is bound to, and it contains an id, a description, and a selected property which is set at the time the value is retrieved.  I realize I screwed up in making this question as GridView doesn't support multiple row selection (and I am using telerik controls).  I am not binding to a selected property on my entity, but to a collection of selected values.  I'm not sure how to define the selection binding.

Comment: So, the list of selected items is not in a table, but some other sort of entity. Is it available at the time you're creating the SQL? Can you build the SQL (maybe a decode()?) in such a way as to determine whether it should be Y or N?

select c.id, c.name, case c.id 
  <% loop through entity(ies) %>
  when entity then 'N'
  <% end loop %>

Comment: See the updated code section in the answer.  It's just too hard to show code in comments.  :)

Comment: I'm looking for the ASP.NET markup that will declare the data binding that I've described on my question.  I have an entity, and a list of choices bound to a grid.  I want to bind a collection property on my entity to the selected choices in the bound grid, and I want to know if there is a way to declare the data binding with asp.net markup, or if it will always require code behind / event handlding.

Comment: I can't imagine that you're going to be able to bind a single control to two (disparate) things at the same time.  You need to combine them in some way, either in SQL or I bet you could do it the _opposite_ way and have a collection include both the values and selectedness attributes.  Otherwise, yes, you would need code behind, either in an event handler or after the fact.